# PHP: Separate Area Code from Phone number with MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, regex, phone-number

I want to separate the area code from a phone number string by using a area code mysql database.

For example the string is `0349152023`.
The endresult should be `03491 52023`.

To get the endresult, i want to split the string and search every digit in database.
For example `0` and then `3` and then `4` and then take the last found result.

The code i have at the moment is only to prepare the phone number string for futher actions:

```
$phone1 = preg_replace('/[oO]/', '0', $phone-string);

$phone2 = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone1);
```

Then i use `str_split` to cut the string in pieces:

```
$searchArray = str_split($phone2);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So if the string starts with `03` you want to split the first 5 integers from the remaining, or can you define a bit more? For example this https://regex101.com/r/vbLNgI/1/ would match your first example. Area codes in my country are only 3 digits though, are all your phone numbers from just one country?

Comment: *0 and than 3 and than 4 and than take the last found result.* Not clear what this means

Comment: `by using a area code mysql database` so you have a table with all your valid area codes?

Comment: Hi chris85 and apokryfos, thanks for your response. The area codes are from germany. They aren't determinted by an specific quantity of digits. For example in switzerland an area code has always only 3 digits, in germany the area code has 3 to 6 digits. you don't know where it starts and where it ends. So you need a database and run the phone number string against these database. The easiest way in my opinion is to split the phone number string in single digits and search the database digit for digit.

Comment: What is in the areacode table?  `0`, `3`, `4`?  Or `0`, `03`, `034`?  Or something else?

Comment: no it is something like 

034 | 
0341 |
0342 |
0343 |
03431 |
03432 |
035 |

around 5000 entries. The solution to save these 5000 entries in an array and than search the array takes to long time. I think it would be better to search directly in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1: select all area codes from db and put them into an array `$areaCodes`

step 2: iterate over $areaCodes as $code and check if the phonenumber starts with $code. if it does, create a string that has a whitespace between the code and the rest of the number

```
$phonenumber = '0349152023';

$preparedPhonenumber = '';
foreach($areaCodes as $code){
    if(str_pos($phonenumber, $code) === 0){
        // phonenumber starts with areacode

        $phoneWithoutCode = substr($phonenumber, strlen($code));
        $preparedPhonenumber = $code.' '.$phoneWithoutCode;

        break;
    }
}
// if one of the areaCodes was 0349,
// the variable $preparedPhonenumber is now '0349 152023'
```

**edit**: you can shorten the amount of returned area codes from db by selecting only those that start with a certain string.

Let's assume the shortest area code in germany is 3 digits long (which i think is correct).

```
$threeDigits = substr($phonenumber,0,3);
$query = "SELECT * from areacodes
         WHERE code like '".$threeDigits."%'
         ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(code) DESC";
```

this will drastically shrink down the probable area codes array, therefore making the script faster.

**edit** 2: added order by clause in query so the above code will check for longer areacodes first. (the `break;` in the foreach loop is now obligatory!)

Comment: Hi Cashbee, thanks for your support, your time and help. I tried your solution, It works fine with some changes (see below), but the script takes to long time to run through 5000 database entries.

Comment: That makes sense. I will try your Solution tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may build an array containing all the area codes.
Then you may write something like this:

```
foreach ($area_codes as $code) {
  if (substr($phone, 0, strlen($code)) == $code) {
    $phone_string = substr($phone, 0, strlen($code))." ".substr($phone, strlen($code));
  }
}
```

You can obviously add a controller in order to verify if the area code was found or not.

Comment: funny how we suggested almost the exact same thing at the same time. tips about your code: 1: when concatenating your $phone_string, the first part can be replaced by $code. 2: break out of loop after a code match has been found. it makes the code faster ;) here, have an upvote, i know having less than 50 reputation can be rough. cheers

Comment: Hi Cashbee and Leonardo, great thanks for your help and for your time so much. I will try your solutions tomorrow.

Comment: Is it a problem that the area code database contains more than 5000 area codes (germany has 5.237 preselction codes :-). Can i put 5000 entries in an array, without performance problems?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Leonardo Gugliotti and Cashbee

i sort the areaCodes to get a better match. The php scripts works fine, but takes to long time to handle 5000 MySQL entries. Is it possible to make the foreach search directly in mySQL?

```
<?php
$sample_area_codes = array( '0350', '034', '034915', '03491', '0348', '0349', '03491', '034916', '034917',);
sort($sample_area_codes);

$phone_string = '0349152023';

foreach ($sample_area_codes as $code) {
    $subString = substr($phone_string, 0, strlen($code));
    if ($subString == $code) {
        $phone = $subString." ".substr($phone_string, strlen($code));
    }
}

if (!empty($phone)) {
    echo $phone;
}

else {
    echo "No AreaCode found.";
}
?>
```

Output: 034915 2023, which is correct

Comment: What makes the first one be "wrong" and second be right?  Maybe the longer one wins?  _To help you, we need to understand the "rules" of this game._

Comment: When you have a phone number string which is "0349152023" you need to find the longest possibile arecode in the database. If there is no entry in database of "0349152" than "034915" is the right areacode. The problem is that german areacodes aren't distinctiv. One areacode can include another one. For example 0212 Solingen and 02129 Haan. The Area Code of Solingen is a Part of the Area Code of Haan. Both are different cities and have nothing in common

Answer (score 0):

A single probe (assuming `INDEX(area_code)`):

```
 SELECT ...
     FROM AreaCodes
     WHERE area_code < ?
     ORDER BY area_code DESC
     LIMIT 1;
```

(Where you bind the `$phone_number` as a string into the `?`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better split your database into a tree, making a table for each digit.
So the third digit could refer to the second, the fourth to the third, and so on until you reach the maximum lenght of the prefix. The last table should include the name of the area.
Following your example, supposing that the maximum lenght of the area code was five digits, the fifth_digit_table should have at least four fields like these:
ID
IDref
Number
Name

10 records may have the same IDref, corresponding to the number "2" at the fourth position, linked to the previous "021" through the fourth_digit_table, the three_digit_table and so on; only one among these records, that with the Number field filled with "9", should have the Name "Haan"; the others, if there aren't any, should have the Name "Solingen".
I hope you will manage to speed up your script.

Comment: Hi Leonardo, that is i think the Royal Solution for These Problem. I read about your Solution here https://forum.selfhtml.org/self/2003/apr/19/ort-aus-telefonnummer-erkennen/387540

Comment: But i'm not familiar enough with MySQL to implement these solution.